# The view HomePage.views.signin didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

*this is my views.py file where the signin page is not getting loaded and showing the error while am clicking on signin*

**"The view HomePage.views.signin didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."**

could any one place help me out

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from. models import student
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.shortcuts import redirect


# Create your views here.
def HomePage(request):
    return render(request,'index.html',{'link':"https://cloudbinary.io/"})

def signup(request):
    return render(request,'signup.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name    =request.POST["name"]
        email   =request.POST["email"]
        mobile  =request.POST["mobile"]
        Password=request.POST["password"]
        course  =request.POST["course"]

        if student.objects.filter(Email=email).exists():
            messages.info(request,'email already in use')
            return redirect('signup')
        else:
            Student =student(Name=name,Email=email,phone=mobile,Course=course,Password=Password)
            Student.save()
            print("user created")
        
    return render(request,'signup.html')  

def signin(request):

        if request.method=='POST':

            email1=request.POST['email1']
            Password1=request.POST['Password1']

            stud=auth.authenticate(Email=email1,Password=Password1)
            if stud is None:
                auth.login(request,stud)
                return redirect("/signin/")
           
            else:
                messages.info(request,'invalid credentials')
                return redirect('login.html')
```

Comment: if the method is not `POST` returns `None` because there is no return at the end of the function that wrap this case.

Answer (score 0):

when request.method=='GET', there is no return in your code

Answer (score 0):

Every django view must return a `HttpResponse` object, in your case - if `signin` view receives HTTP methods other than `POST` it will return nothing. So you need to add something like:

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        email1=request.POST['email1']
        Password1=request.POST['Password1']

        stud=auth.authenticate(Email=email1,Password=Password1)
        if stud is None:
            auth.login(request,stud)
            return redirect("/signin/")
           
        else:
            messages.info(request,'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login.html')
    # For handling other methods
    else:
        return redirect('login.html')
```